# swift: fix buttons animation

Tags: ios, swift

When my app stat I want to show buttons animation. In storyboard my buttons have `height = 50` and `y = -50`. I have this action in code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonAnimation()
}

func buttonAnimation() 
{
    self.buttonTopConstraint.constant += self.ButtonHeightConstraint.constant
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: 
        {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    )
}
```

Animation work well. But when app start my background imageView in `storyboard` and different imageView animated too. But I need to have only animation for button. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call animation in `viewDidLoad` because at that time all views of your controller are going to set.

Use `viewDidAppear` to call animation method.

```
  override func viewDidAppear() 
   {
    buttonAnimation()
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGAffineTransform` to animate your button. `Remove y=-50` from storyboard and keep it at its desired place. Then call this function in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` :

```
func animateButton() {
    yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: yourButton.frame.origin.x, y: yourButton.frame.origin.y - 50)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.yourButton.transform = .identity
    }, completion: nil)
}
```